# How does the runtime distinguish the nature of a variable running in the stack?

Tags: c#

Just curious. We have different variables in the stack, value types as well as reference types. My understanding is that the value in a reference variable is either a 32-bit or 64-bit integer. value type contains their payload (as opposed to the reference type that contains the memory address). Bytes take up 1 byte while DateTime and Long all go all the way to 8 bytes.

**How the runtime can tell which one is what?** What's the mechanism? How does the runtime know to treat a **reference** as one instead of just another **integer**?

Thanks for helping

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think the intuitive answer is: the same way it distinguishes between an `int` and a `uint` variables, for example. Or basically any two variables of different types.

Comment: Perhaps as in x86 assembler there are memory addresses and offsets.The variable is defined and when compiled into IL inserts the size that is stored on the stack

Comment: This question is too broad. The short answer is the CLI is innately aware of every type it deals with, and how much room it takes up. The long answer is a deep dive through the CLI specifications and a long winded talk about all the mechanics and moving parts in a compiled application. If you are morbidly interested you can take a look at the specs yourself. https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf

Comment: This gets decided very early, before the runtime gets to it.  The C# compiler determines what operations on a value or object reference are valid.  So you can, say, add two int values but not two object references.  At runtime there's but the verifier built in the CLR that double-checks these operations.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example in C# and IL with a method call and two local variables.

As follows from the description of the method stloc_0: ["The stloc.0 instruction pops the top value off the evaluation stack and moves it into the local variable indexed by 0. **The type of the value must match the type of the local variable** as specified in the current method's local signature."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc_0?view=net-5.0)

C# Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 5;
    DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Call(i);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}

private static int Call(int i = 0)
{
    return i++;
}
```

IL Code

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // 36 (0x24)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (int32 V_0,
           valuetype [System.Runtime]System.DateTime V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  call       valuetype [System.Runtime]System.DateTime [System.Runtime]System.DateTime::get_UtcNow()
  IL_0008:  stloc.1
  IL_0009:  ldloc.0
  IL_000a:  call       int32 ConsoleApp22.Program::Call(int32)
  IL_000f:  pop
  IL_0010:  ldloc.0
  IL_0011:  call       void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_0016:  nop
  IL_0017:  ldloc.1
  IL_0018:  box        [System.Runtime]System.DateTime
  IL_001d:  call       void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
  IL_0022:  nop
  IL_0023:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism relies on the **metadata** stored in the assembly.

The best way to see it for yourself is to use ILSpy.

Given a super simple console application:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            string var1 = "Hello ";

            string var2 = "World!";

            Console.WriteLine(var1 + var2);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what you will get in ILSpy if you choose to view **IL with C#** (and also the metadata tokens from View>Options>Display>Treeview Options>Show metadata token)
[image]

the information about the .locals you see

```
.locals /* 11000001 */ init (
    [0] string var1,
    [1] string var2
)
```

comes from the **StandAloneSig table** from the metadata via the metadata-token 11000001 (which you can access via ILSpy too - right-pane in the screenshot)

For more detailed information about metadata and IL, you can dive into the book by Serge Lidin - .NET IL Assembler (last edition from 2014). Much more friendly explanation of complex inner workings than the ECMA standard.
Quote from it from page 149 regarding the OP's question.

> "Local variables signatures are the second type of signatures
> referenced by the StandAloneSig metadata table. Each such signature
> contains type encodings for all local variables used in a method. The
> method header can contain the StandAloneSig token, which identifies
> the local variables signature. This signature is retrieved by the
> loader when it prepares the method for JIT compilation."